# hash remove item key and value

Tags: ruby

I have the following hash:

```
{
  "itens":
  [
     {"year": "2018", "data": "id": 1},
     {"year": "2018", "data": "id": 2}
  ]
}
```

I need to insert another element to the array of hashes. But I can't have a duplicate entry.

So I have to insert this line:

```
{"year": "2019", "data": "id": 2}
```

But first I need to remove the previous:

```
{"year": "2018", "data": "id": 2}
```

How can I iterate over the hash, find key and value, remove and add the new entry ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean a hash like this:

```
 hash = { 
   items: [
     {year: 2018, data: { id: 1 }},
     {year: 2018, data: { id: 2 }}
   ]
 }
```

Than you can change it for example in this way:

```
item = {year: 2019, data: { id: 2 }}
hash[:items].delete_if do |stored_hash|
    stored_hash[:data][:id] == item[:data][:id]
end
hash[:items] << item
```

Than it would result in this:

```
hash

=> {:items=>[{:year=>2018, :data=>{:id=>1}}, {:year=>2019, :data=>{:id=>2}}]}
```

I hope this answers your question...

Answer (score 0):

Given the variables:

```
myhash = {
  "itens":
  [
     {"year": "2018", "data": nil, "id": 1},
     {"year": "2018", "data": nil, "id": 2}
  ]
}

insert = {"year": "2019", "data": "something", "id": 2}
remove = {"year": "2018", "data": nil, "id": 2}
```

If `insert` and `remove` have the same keys, you can do:

```
myhash[:'itens'].find { |h| h[:'id'] == insert[:'id'] }.merge! insert

#=> {:itens=>[{:year=>"2018", :data=>nil, :id=>1}, {:year=>"2019", :data=>"something", :id=>2}]}
```